# How to call HTTPS Api in pl/sql procedure using UTL_HTTP package?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm encountering challenges while attempting to call an HTTPS API service from a PL/SQL procedure using the UTL_HTTP package. I've successfully managed to invoke an HTTP service, but I'm facing difficulties with HTTPS calls.

Could someone proficient with this process guide me through the necessary steps for securely invoking an HTTPS API service using PL/SQL and UTL_HTTP? I'd greatly appreciate insights or examples illustrating how to handle HTTPS requests successfully within a PL/SQL procedure, including any specific configurations or potential troubleshooting steps to ensure the HTTPS call works as intended.

**This is my pl/sql code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE call_api (
  p_name IN VARCHAR2,
  p_age IN NUMBER
) IS
  req utl_http.req;
  res utl_http.resp;
  url VARCHAR2(4000) := 'https://qh5rz7xna7.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/sample';
  buffer VARCHAR2(4000);
  content VARCHAR2(4000) := '{"name":"' || p_name || '","age":' || p_age || '}';
BEGIN
  req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(content));
 
  utl_http.write_text(req, content);
  res := utl_http.get_response(req);

  -- Process the response from the HTTP call
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
      dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
    END LOOP;
    utl_http.end_response(res);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
      utl_http.end_response(res);
  END;
END call_api;
/


SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

BEGIN
  call_api('john', 20);
END;
```

**This is created ACL**

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
    acl          => 'local_sx_acl_file.xml', 
    description  => 'A test of the ACL functionality',
    principal    => 'AMILA',
    is_grant     => TRUE, 
    privilege    => 'connect',
    start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    end_date     => NULL);
end;
 
begin
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (
    acl         => 'local_sx_acl_file.xml',
    host        => '*', 
    lower_port  => NULL,
    upper_port  => NULL);    
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Had some problems with this recently. Not sure if this could help you, but here is what I have done to get it working:

1. created new folder for wallet (something like: C:\some_dir\wallets)

- gave full control privilages to the user calling api (folder properties - Security tab)
  [image]

2. added to .ora files definitions of wallet location and authentication

```sql
#listener.ora
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = your_wallet_folder_path)
    )
  )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
#tnsnames.ora
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = your_wallet_folder_path)
     )
   )
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#sqlnet.ora
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = your_wallet_folder_path)
     )
   )
   
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS,NTS,BEQ)
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

3. downloaded and saved certificates from api address - it will be added to the wallet in next step

   - there are several types - I got them all - the one that worked was chain .p7c
4. Created new wallet using Walet Manager app (type .p12)

   - requested certificate
   - added trusted certificate extension .p7c (chain)
   - opened wallet menu and checked auto login box
   - saved wallet in folder your_wallet_folder_path

- find it at All programs menu under Oracle folder
  [image]

5. About plsql code

   - put parameters (if there are any) in url directly using concatinations for special chars like &

```sql
        -- v_url  := v_endpoint || v_path || '?api-version=3.0' || '&' || 'from=hr' || '&' || 'to=en'
```

- construct propper json object if expected in content (body)

```sql
Select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'text' VALUE 'some text in some language') RETURNING CLOB) Into v_body From Dual;
```

PL/SQL Code - for text translation api

```sql
create or replace procedure "TEST"
is
BEGIN
    Declare
        v_key       VarChar2(64) := 'your api key';
        v_endpoint  VarChar2(64) := 'https://api.some_api_addres.com';
        v_path      VarChar2(64) := '/translate';
        v_location  VarChar2(64) := 'another api check';
      --
        v_body      CLOB := empty_clob();
        v_buffer    VarChar2(32767);
        --
        mReq        UTL_HTTP.req;
        mResp       UTL_HTTP.resp;
        v_url       VarChar2(128) := v_endpoint || v_path || '?api-version=3.0' || '&' || 'from=hr' || '&' || 'to=en';
    Begin
         Select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'text' VALUE 'some text in some language') RETURNING CLOB) Into v_body From Dual;

        UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET('UTF-8');
        UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout (30);
        UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('file:your_wallet_folder_path', 'your_wallet_password');

        mReq := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(v_url, 'POST');
        
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'Your-Api-Subscription-Key', v_key);
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'Your-Api-Some-Other-Check', v_location);
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'ClientTraceUUID', MK_GUID());  -- constructs uuid
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'Content-type', 'application/json');
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'Content-Length', length(v_body));
        
        UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(mReq, v_body);

        mResp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(mReq);

        begin
            loop
                utl_http.read_line(mResp, v_buffer);
                dbms_output.put_line(v_buffer);
            end loop;
            utl_http.end_response(mResp);
        exception
            when utl_http.end_of_body then
                utl_http.end_response(mResp);
        end;

    Exception
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm);
            utl_http.end_response(mResp);
    End;
END;
```

Comment: how did you give full control privileges?can you provide ACL code.

Comment: i'm confuced about oracle wallet. can you tell me how did you create oracle wallet and added certificates. i created wallet opening cmd as administrator then added certificates with .cer file. in my certificate export wizard couldn't find .p7c, i can find .p7b

Comment: @amilaupendra Just posted an update. Full control is for folder on your database server OS. Mine is Windows. And Wallet Manager is the  App on  All programs menu under Oracle folder. Sorry for missing to tell it in the answer. The app is quite simple and straight forward...

Comment: @d r  what is the difference between chain certificates and storing certificates (.cer / .crt) .  i just downloaded certificates and and got base-64 encoded X.509(.cer) and stored in wallet. am i wrong?

Comment: @amilaupendra I realy don't know. As far as I understood it - Oracle, for https third party connections, demands a wallet type .p12 (default for Wallet Manager App) and that type of wallet doesn't treat encription in a way that .crt/.cer/.der/.... certificates do. In my case even the single .p7c didn't work - just chain .p7c. I suppose that there is something on the other (api) side that should be met too. Just don't know. Sorry.