# "Failure to open file" when trying to make a request through UTL_HTTP

Tags: oracle, oracle21c

Setup:
Windows 11 22H2
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
SQLDeveloper version 22.1.2.234 build 234.1810

I'm trying to follow [UTL_HTTP and SSL](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl) to make a request to an HTTPS endpoint.

I have followed the tutorial to:

1. To add an ACE for a test user to allow it to make requests through UTL_HTTP for oracle-base.com:
   select * from dba_host_acls;
   [ACLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPIZr.png)

select * from dba_host_aces;
[ACES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93QLE.png)

2. Export SSL certificate for https://oracle-base.com: ISRG Root X1 to a .CRTfile.
3. Create wallet using:

```
orapki wallet create -wallet .\wallet -pwd Password123 -auto_login
```

The wallet is created at folder `C:\users\Lenovo\wallet`.
4. Add the SSL certificate to wallet using

```
orapki wallet add -wallet .\wallet -trusted_cert -cert C:\users\Lenovo\Downloads\ISRGRootX1.crt -pwd Password123
```

5. Verify certificate is added as trusted certificate using:

```
orapki wallet display -wallet wallet

Oracle PKI Tool Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 2004, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Requested Certificates:
User Certificates:
Trusted Certificates:
Subject:        CN=ISRG Root X1,O=Internet Security Research Group,C=US
```

Now, when I provide the wallet path and try to make an HTTPS request, it throws the following error:

```
**[Run from SQL Developer. Shows Running as "Lenovo" user in task manager]**
set serveroutput on
exec utl_http.set_wallet('**file:///C:/users/lenovo/wallet**', 'Password123');
exec show_html_from_url('https://oracle-base.com/');

Error starting at line : 3 in command -
BEGIN show_html_from_url('https://oracle-base.com/'); END;
Error report -
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "TEST1.SHOW_HTML_FROM_URL", line 33
ORA-28759: **failure to open file**
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
ORA-06512: at "TEST1.SHOW_HTML_FROM_URL", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

If I open **file:///C:/users/lenovo/wallet** directly through windows run, it opens the wallet folder so I'm pretty sure that the path to the wallet is correct. The cwallet.sso, ewallet.p12 files are present within this folder.

I have searched for this issue a lot and it is pointed everywhere this happens **when the database can't access the wallet file.**

I opened Oracle Instance Manager and found this:
[Oracle Run As](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEICm.png). So with this in mind, I assumed Oracle Database runs as orcl_admin.

I changed owner of wallet folder and the files within to "orcl_admin" and added "Full Control" for orcl_admin to the wallet folder and the files within:

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo> Get-Acl .\wallet\ | format-list


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet\
**Owner  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin**
Group  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\None
**Access : DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin Allow  FullControl**
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         DESKTOP-BDS391A\Lenovo Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361732-4164690872-1018G:S-1-5-21-3701882
         691-2603361732-4164690872-513D:AI(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3701882691-
         2603361732-4164690872-1018)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;FA;;;BA)(A;
         OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361732-4164690872-1001)


PS C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet> Get-Acl .\cwallet.sso | Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet\cwall
         et.sso
**Owner  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin**
Group  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\None
Access : DESKTOP-BDS391A\Lenovo Allow  Write, Delete, Read,
         ChangePermissions, Synchronize
**         DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin Allow  FullControl**
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361732-4164690872-1018G:S-1-5-21-3701882
         691-2603361732-4164690872-513D:PAI(A;;0x17019f;;;S-1-5-21-37018826
         91-2603361732-4164690872-1001)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361
         732-4164690872-1018)

PS C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet> Get-Acl .\cwallet.sso.lck | Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet\cwall
         et.sso.lck
**Owner  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin**
Group  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\None
Access : DESKTOP-BDS391A\Lenovo Allow  Write, Delete, Read,
         ChangePermissions, Synchronize
**         DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin Allow  FullControl**
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361732-4164690872-1018G:S-1-5-21-3701882
         691-2603361732-4164690872-513D:PAI(A;;0x17019f;;;S-1-5-21-37018826
         91-2603361732-4164690872-1001)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361
         732-4164690872-1018)

PS C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet> Get-Acl .\ewallet.p12 | Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet\ewall
         et.p12
**Owner  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin**
Group  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\None
Access : DESKTOP-BDS391A\Lenovo Allow  Write, Delete, Read,
         ChangePermissions, Synchronize
**         DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin Allow  FullControl**
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361732-4164690872-1018G:S-1-5-21-3701882
         691-2603361732-4164690872-513D:PAI(A;;0x17019f;;;S-1-5-21-37018826
         91-2603361732-4164690872-1001)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361
         732-4164690872-1018)

PS C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet> Get-Acl .\ewallet.p12.lck | Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Lenovo\wallet\ewall
         et.p12.lck
**Owner  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin**
Group  : DESKTOP-BDS391A\None
Access : DESKTOP-BDS391A\Lenovo Allow  Write, Delete, Read,
         ChangePermissions, Synchronize
**         DESKTOP-BDS391A\orcl_admin Allow  FullControl**
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361732-4164690872-1018G:S-1-5-21-3701882
         691-2603361732-4164690872-513D:PAI(A;;0x17019f;;;S-1-5-21-37018826
         91-2603361732-4164690872-1001)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3701882691-2603361
         732-4164690872-1018)
```

Even with all this, it still throws the error "failure to open file".
Can anyone share any pointers to diagnose this error?

What I tried:

1. Changed owner of wallet folder to orcl_admin and added "Full Control" for orcl_admin.
2. Verified that the wallet path is correct by opening it in Windows run (Win + R).
3. Verified that the intended certificate is in the wallet folder.
4. Look at eventviewer > Windows Logs > Application. The event logs are somewhat cryptic and don't elaborate much on the error.

What actually resulted?
The error still persists.

What I expected to happen?
After changing ACLs, Owner on the wallet folder, I expected it to no longer run into "Failure to open file" error.

Comment: Try this path for the wallet: file:c:\users\lenovo\wallet 

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_HTTP.html#GUID-D4063487-6F69-4757-B77A-AF2B93E5DAFE

Answer (score 0):

Check .ora files definitions for wallet location and authentication

```sql
#listener.ora
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = your_wallet_folder_path)
    )
  )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
#tnsnames.ora
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = your_wallet_folder_path)
     )
   )
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#sqlnet.ora
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = your_wallet_folder_path)
     )
   )
   
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS,NTS,BEQ)
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my case the only certificate that worked with Oracle wallet (p12) was .p7c **Chain** certificate. I used Oracle wallet manager app to create and setup the wallet. The full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77502021/how-to-call-https-api-in-pl-sql-procedure-using-utl-http-package/77524247#77524247).