# In oracle, ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure

Tags: oracle, plsql, acl, utl-http

My plsql for accessing intranet site

```
DECLARE
  l_url            VARCHAR2(50) := 'https://www.domainname.net';
  l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
  l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
BEGIN
  -- Make a HTTP request and get the response.
  utl_http.set_wallet('file:WALLETPATH', pass);
  l_http_request  := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(l_url);
  l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);
  UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
END;
```

receiving below error

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
ORA-06512: at line 9

/sys/acls/domainname-net-permissions.xml    [www.domainname.net](http://www.domainname.net)  GRANTED

please help in clearing the error

Wallet already created and it is displaying correctly using orapki wallet display -wallet command. Still receives certificate validation failure. But in browser the domain is able to access in the server. Only from oracle it is receiving this error

Comment: Maybe you could get the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77502021/how-to-call-https-api-in-pl-sql-procedure-using-utl-http-package/77524247#77524247

Comment: Did you import the CA certificate into the Wallet?

Comment: yes i had import CA certificate and using orapki wallet display certifactes are displayed